403 error with some pages when extracting data on some URLs
"Hello, can you help me? When trying to extract a JSON file from a webpage, it works with some URLs from the same page, but with others, I get a 403 error. The URLs are:"
ok: https://www.falabella.com/falabella-cl/category/cat16510006/Electrohogar?facetSelected=true&f.derived.variant.sellerId=FALABELLA%3A%3ASODIMAC%3A%3ATOTTUS&page=1
error 403:
https://www.falabella.com/falabella-cl/category/cat7330051/Mujer?facetSelected=true&f.derived.variant.sellerId=FALABELLA&page=1
my sample code:
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


session = requests.Session()
session.headers.update({
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36'
})


def extract_json_from_falabella(url):
    try:
        response = session.get(url)
        response.raise_for_status()  # Lanza una excepción si la respuesta no es exitosa (código 2xx)

        if response.status_code == 200:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
           
            script_tag = soup.find('script', id='__NEXT_DATA__')

            if script_tag:
               
                json_text = script_tag.string.strip()
                data = json.loads(json_text)
                return data
            else:
                print("No se encontró el script con id='__NEXT_DATA__'.")
                return None
        else:
            print(f"Error al realizar la solicitud: {response.status_code}")
            return None

    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as http_err:
        print(f"Error HTTP: {http_err}")
        return None
    except Exception as err:
        print(f"Ocurrió un error: {err}")
        return None


url = "https://www.falabella.com/falabella-cl/category/cat7330051/Mujer?facetSelected=true&f.derived.variant.sellerId=FALABELLA%3A%3ASODIMAC&page=1"
data = extract_json_from_falabella(url)

if data:
  
    with open('falabella_data.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as json_file:
        json.dump(data, json_file, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
    print("Datos guardados en 'falabella_data.json'")
else:
    print("No se pudieron extraer los datos JSON.")

can you see the problem?

You're being blocked by Cloudflare. Reading other posts, for many people just setting the User-Agent bypasses this issue. This answer advises you may need to set other headers in the request as well. I tried adding some request headers found in Dev Console (along with User-Agent) but unfortunately no luck. Someone more experienced than I could probably figure it out--essentially you need to emulate what your browser is doing through manually sending requests

Here is a zenrows link about bypassing cloudflare 403. They claim it is "complex" to bypass and offer a product (web scraping API) specifically for this

If you can't figure out a way to bypass cloudflare, you could try Selenium (in headless mode, don't actually need to see the browser) to open the page and get the source. That approach may also require configuration to avoid cloudflare detection

This is Cloudflare protection, I don't know why it's only applied on some paths but not others, but this is passive protection and it uses tls/ja3/http2 fingerprinting to block bots/scraping.
Fortunately it can be bypassed in this scenario by impersonating the browser's fingerprints with curl_cffi which has a requests like api.
Since this site uses an api, we can retrieve data directly in json format, instead of extracting it from the html.
The code below will retrieve the results for the this page:
https://www.falabella.com/falabella-cl/category/cat7330051/Mujer?facetSelected=true&f.derived.variant.sellerId=FALABELLA&page=1
from curl_cffi import requests

def get_pid():
    url = 'https://www.falabella.com/s/geo/v2/districts/cl?politicalId=default'
    response = requests.get(url)
    data = response.json().get('data', {})
    return data.get('politicalId')


api_url = "https://www.falabella.com/s/browse/v1/listing/cl"

# pid does not seem to change/expire so you can replace it with string value
pid = get_pid()

params = {
    'f.derived.variant.sellerId': 'FALABELLA',
    'facetSelected': True,
    'page': 1,
    'categoryId': 'cat7330051',
    'categoryName': 'Mujer',
    'pid': pid,
}

response = requests.get(api_url, params=params, impersonate='chrome')
data = response.json()['data']

pagination = data['pagination']
results = data['results']

print(f'{len(results) = }')

Don't forget to install curl_cffi using pip:
pip install curl_cffi --upgrade

Note: I have removed 2 params (pgid & zones) that did not seem to do anything, if you notice any discrepancy between these results and the ones in the html (__NEXT_DATA__) you could try adding them back (copy from devtools).
